# How can I set the favicon on the Django administrator site?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a project where the client wants to set the [*favicon.ico* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) as the site logo. How can I set the site logo on the Django administrator site?

I have tried with this code, but it doesn’t work.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    {% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

    {% block extrahead %}
        <link rel="icon" href="{{STATIC_URL}}img/favicon.ico" sizes="48x48" sizes="48x48" />
    {% endblock %}
    {% block branding %}
        <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by site logo?? Favicon or HTML image??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, I think, is in the syntax.

Based on your **static settings**, one of them should work:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/static/admin/img/favicon.ico" sizes="48x48" />
```

Or:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{%  static 'admin/images/favicon.ico' %}" sizes="48x48" />
```

Comment: "GET /admin/auth/user/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
getting this in the log favicon is missing.

Comment: @VinayKumar And what is the actual path of favicon.ico?

Comment: static/admin/img/favicon.ico

Comment: @VinayKumar Edited my answer.Please check.

Comment: still same issue. Can you please explain where we have to put this html file?

Comment: @VinayKumar You need to put this in the base template which is extended or included everywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154683/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-vinay-kumar).

Comment: Yes fav icon is set. Please me how to add site logo in admin site?

Comment: @VinayKumar Site logo should be added where?? Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#jumbotron for index page logo.

Comment: On the top left corner where "Django  administration" on admin site

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I followed and is all based on my intuition.

I went in my Django directory and found all the templates. Something like this:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\PythonDjangoDev\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin

In this directory, you will find all the administrator HTML pages, so go to your *base_site.html* file and modify it as you wish. It was the only solution that worked for me. I put in something like this:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block branding %}

    <h1 id="head">

    <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}"
         alt="BT Real Estate"
         height="50"
         width="80"
         class="brand_img">YOUR TITLE</h1>

{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="{% static 'css/admin.css' %}">

{% endblock %}
```